# How to upload a pdf from iphone using cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, file-upload, cordova-plugins

I Have a requirement to upload a pdf/doc to server when i put `<input type='file'>` its only giving access to `Gallery`. I Know due to `security reasons` this will not allow to access other things but is their any other way to do this. If yes please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 9, the input type file has access to "document providers", that means, if you have apps installed that can handle files (dropbox, drive, onedrive, etc), they will appear as options and once you choose it you can use an ajax call to send it to the server.

If you want to support iOS 8 you can use [my file picker plugin](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin) that will allow you to choose files from document providers
And once the plugin retun the file url, you have to use [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to send it to the server.

```
window.FilePicker.pickFile(successCallback,errorCallback);
```

On `successCallback` you'll get the file url

If the .doc/.pdf is generated by your app and/or it in your app sandbox because you downloaded it previously, you can use the [cordova-plugin-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) to get the file url and then you can use the `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` plugin to upload it to the server too

Answer (score 1):

There's a [plugin for file transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) with the function you need:

Example:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Comment: how can i acess the the pdf file first of all

Comment: Again: There's a plugin for that purpose: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: I have that plugin added for choosing a particular file how this will help

Comment: can you see my question thoroughly...?